# Magento Cant able to save Product

Tags: magento-1.9, product

While Save Product I got Error. I don't know what is the problem suddenly it happen

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
>   '16963-1' for key
>   'UNQ_CATALOGINVENTORY_STOCK_ITEM_PRODUCT_ID_STOCK_ID', query was:
>   INSERT INTO `cataloginventory_stock_item` (`product_id`, `stock_id`,
>   `qty`, `use_config_min_qty`, `is_qty_decimal`,
>   `use_config_backorders`, `use_config_min_sale_qty`,
>   `use_config_max_sale_qty`, `is_in_stock`, `low_stock_date`,
>   `use_config_notify_stock_qty`, `use_config_manage_stock`,
>   `stock_status_changed_auto`, `use_config_qty_increments`,
>   `use_config_enable_qty_inc`, `is_decimal_divided`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?,
>   ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the line

```
$product->save();
```

to

```
$product->getResource()->save($product);
```

Hope this will help

Comment: Can you please tell me the file location

Comment: did you changed any file before or what is the reason you are getting this error?

Comment: I din't change anything while save product i got this error

Comment: Did you created any product attribute from admin backend?

Comment: No recently i din't create

Comment: OK, I am not sure why you are getting this error, you can change the code as above in `Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController` file but changing the core files is very dangerous.

Comment: Ok i will check and let you know